# Issue with datetime picker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I have the code like below

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <h2>Jquery - Timepicker Example using jQuery Timepicker Plugin</h2>
    <strong>Select Time:</strong> <input type="text" id="timepicker" class="from-control">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#timepicker").timepicker(
    {
        timeFormat: 'H:mm ',
        interval: 1,
        minTime: '12am',
        maxTime: '23.59',
        startTime: '12am',
        dynamic: true,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true
    });


</script>
```

it is working correctly first time, but after that it is not working. 
when I click on the text box then timepicker will appear but when I click second time on the text box then time picker will not appear in my code
and it is showing error that, "can not read property children of undefine" in the inspect of the browser

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: You need to include these line before the code     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.3/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.3/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you give us the exact details of the error. It seems unrelated to the code you've shown, so it would seem that we need to see more of your code in order to help you

Comment: @TanveerKhan was that comment an attempt to answer your own question?

Comment: I think your time picker plugin is initialised  multiple times. Show us your full code or make a snippet/fiddle to understand it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan looks like that comment was the extra includes needed to get the sample working.     Tanveer - add that to your question via an edit.

Comment: Thank you. when I click first time on text box then timepicker appear but after page refresh timepicker is not appeared. above code is not exact what I have .I have code in Edit panel of controller

Comment: scene is Like that  when I click Edit button then pop up of edit panel appear with time field .when  I click on time field then timepicker appear but when I cancel the pop up and again click on edit button then time picker does not appear imn edit panel

Comment: So depends on how your popups are generated/cleared-down.  It's likely that the `<input id=timepicker>` is being destroyed and recreated, in which case your timepicker no longer applies (as the control it was applied to no longer exists).  You can get around this by re-applying the `.timerpicker({..})` every time your popup is shown.

Comment: I used code from https://timepicker.co/ here

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap you code in the document ready event, so that it runs only once...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#timepicker").timepicker(
    {
        timeFormat: 'H:mm ',
        interval: 1,
        minTime: '12am',
        maxTime: '23.59',
        startTime: '12am',
        dynamic: true,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried it but not working error is in jquery time picker plug in . I used code from here https://timepicker.co/